# Compare 2 Columns in DataTable to 2 Columns in List and build a new List with certain criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have `DataTable`

```cs
public static DataTable SubProjects = new DataTable();

public static DataTable GetSubProjects
{
    get { return SubProjects; }
}
```

it comes from database so columns are as follows

```cs
select ProjectN,ProjectSubN,ProjectM
```

and list:

```cs
public class SubProjectsList
{
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string SubProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string SubProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectManager { get; set; }
    public int ObjectID { get; set; }

    public SubProjectsList(string ProjectNumber, string SubProjectNumber, string SubProjectName, string ProjectManager, int ObjectID)
    {
        this.ProjectNumber = ProjectNumber;
        this.SubProjectNumber = SubProjectNumber;
        this.SubProjectName = SubProjectName;
        this.ProjectManager = ProjectManager;
        this.SubProjectNumber = SubProjectNumber;
        this.ObjectID = ObjectID;
    }
}

public static List<SubProjectsList> DeliverySubProjectList = new List<SubProjectsList>();
```

Ultimately I would like to get all results to new List where

```
ProjectN + ProjectSubN (DataTable) = ProjectNumber + SubProjectNumber (List) && 
ProjectM (DataTable) != ProjectManager (List)
```

As an output I need to get `ProjectNumber`, `SubProjectNumber`, `ProjectM`, `ProjectManager`. Basically I need to catch `ProjectM` and `ProjectManager` that does not match for one sub-project. I could have done it this way

```cs
var SubProjectResult = SubProjects.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => DeliverySubProjectList.Any(y => 
    y.ProjectNumber.Trim() + y.SubProjectNumber == x.Field<string>("ProjectN").Trim() + x.Field<string>("ProjectSubN").Trim() &&
    !string.Equals(y.ProjectManager.Trim(), x.Field<string>("ProjectM").Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ProjectN = x.Field<string>("ProjectN"),
        ProjectN = x.Field<string>("ProjectSubN"),
        ProjectM = x.Field<string>("ProjectM"),
        ProjectM = x.ProjectManager // This is not possible
    })
    .OrderBy(o => o.ProjectN).ToList();
```

but

```cs
ProjectM = x.ProjectManager // This is not possible
```

is wrong and does not compile. So I can't get `ProjectManager` from List where `ProjectN + ProjectSubN (DataTable) = ProjectNumber + SubProjectNumber (List)` match but ProjectManager does not match. Do I need to Concat DataTable and List together first? I have tried this

```
var myList1 = SubProjects.AsEnumerable().Concat(DeliverySubProjectList).ToList();
```

but getting an error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1929  'EnumerableRowCollection' does not contain a
> definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload
> 'Queryable.Concat(IQueryable,
> IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type
> 'IQueryable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should give you what you are looking for. You might need to add extra null checks and I am also not very sure about that's how you want to add string values from the list and the data table:

```
public class ResultModel
        {
            public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
            public string SubProjectNumber { get; set; }
            public string ProjectM { get; set; }
            public string ProjectManager { get; set; }
        }

...
...
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SubProjectsList> DeliverySubProjectList = // populate list
            DataTable SubProjects = // populate datatable
            List<ResultModel> results = GetResults(DeliverySubProjectList, SubProjects).ToList();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<ResultModel> GetResults(List<SubProjectsList> DeliverySubProjectList, DataTable SubProjects)
        {
            return SubProjects.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
            {
                var listItem = DeliverySubProjectList.FirstOrDefault(item =>
                {
                    return item.ProjectNumber + item.SubProjectNumber == row["ProjectN"].ToString() + row["ProjectSubN "].ToString()
                        && !item.ProjectManager.Equals(row["ProjectM"].ToString());

                });

                if (listItem != null)
                {
                    return new ResultModel
                    {
                        ProjectNumber = row["ProjectN"].ToString(),
                        SubProjectNumber = listItem.SubProjectNumber,
                        ProjectM = row["ProjectM"].ToString(),
                        ProjectManager = listItem.ProjectManager
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .Where(res => res != null);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Seems like it could solve my problem, but can you also add usage example. I am not quite sure how to implement this method for List creation? `List<(string ProjectNumber, string SubProjectNumber, string ProjectM, string ProjectManager)> SubProjectNumberList =
            new List<(string ProjectNumber, string SubProjectNumber, string ProjectM, string ProjectManager)>();

            SubProjectNumberList = NewMethod(DeliverySubProjectList, SubProjects);` ?